# I have a problem while trying to execute a command with params via Java runtime

Tags: command-line, java, gksu

I'm working on a Java desktop aplication to manage iptables and i want to execute iptables commands via Java, this is what i am doing:

i execute from terminal gksu "iptables -L" and it worked
but when i try to execute it from Java runtime ( exec.("gksu \"iptables -L\" ") )
i keep getting this output:

GKsu version 2.0.2

Usage: gksu [-u ] [options]

--debug, -d

```
Print information on the screen that might be

useful for diagnosing and/or solving problems.
```

--user , -u

```
Call <command> as the specified user.
```

--disable-grab, -g

```
Disable the "locking" of the keyboard, mouse,

and focus done by the program when asking for

password.
```

--prompt, -P

```
Ask the user if they want to have their keyboard

and mouse grabbed before doing so.
```

--preserve-env, -k

```
Preserve the current environments, does not set $HOME

nor $PATH, for example.
```

--login, -l

```
Make this a login shell. Beware this may cause

problems with the Xauthority magic. Run xhost

to allow the target user to open windows on your

display!
```

--description , -D

```
Provide a descriptive name for the command to

be used in the default message, making it nicer.

You can also provide the absolute path for a

.desktop file. The Name key for will be used in

this case.
```

--message , -m

```
Replace the standard message shown to ask for

password for the argument passed to the option.

Only use this if --description does not suffice.
```

--print-pass, -p

```
Ask gksu to print the password to stdout, just

like ssh-askpass. Useful to use in scripts with

programs that accept receiving the password on

stdin.
```

--sudo-mode, -S

```
Make GKSu use sudo instead of su, as if it had been

run as "gksudo".
```

--su-mode, -w

```
Make GKSu use su, instead of using libgksu's

default.
```

I hope someone can help me :D plox :P

Answer (score 3):

You are not doing it right. Make a string array. The first element will be the command name, and the following elements will be arguments. [http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[])](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)